# How to authenticate on EC2 instance via CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

when I check my CodeDeploy error logs, Unable to authenticate on EC2 instance codedeploy. CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller:
Missing credentials - please check if this instance was started with an IAM instance profile
When I try to execute `echo $(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/)` it's getting a 401, which indicates to me there's permission issues.

Currently my EC2 instance has an IAM role with the following roles and policies

```
AmazonEC2RoleforAWSCodeDeploy
AWSCodeDeployRole


{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": [
                "codedeploy.amazonaws.com",
                "ec2.amazonaws.com"
            ]
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
]
}
```

Any tips and suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you also run aws configure before? seems like either role is not attached properly or it is using the AWS credentials to make calls to the instance metadata API.